# What would a sea made of Iodine look like?

Tags: planets, chemistry, ocean, sea, extreme-terrain

If it was possible, what would a sea made of liquid state Iodine look like? How would it smell?

From my research, I've seen people saying its liquid state is somewhat "invisible" since it generates a lot of vapor around it, so it looks always gassy. Also, I suppose it would have a dark red color, but I'm not sure since solid Iodine seems something between black and purple.

Comment: It'd look, smell, and act like iodine. Iodine is liquid all the time, and a sea of it is actually possible if you get enough of it. I haven't smelled iodine, or really messed with it, so i can't give a true answer.

Comment: What are you expecting an answer to tell you?

Comment: @moonheart08: Iodine is a solid in normal conditions. It melts at 114° C.

Comment: @AlexP: I think the OP means the sublimation of iodine at room temperature will result in different properties in the liquid phase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0187893X17301490), iodine can be melted under relatively controlled conditions. Iodine is classically described as a sublimating solid (skips from solid to gaseous state).

The accompanying video shows very clearly that solid iodine crystals can be melted into a very dark inky-purpley-black liquid.

[Melting iodine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=114-6VREZ7o&feature=youtu.be)

So I guess the answer is: if you have a sufficiently stable temperature within the planet, an ocean of iodine will look like very dark, deep, deep purple-black ink and it will smell like iodine. "Mediciney".

Comment: Yeah,it will be close to black liquid, with clouds of violet over it. And sure not a place life can survive. Why it did not react with something?